# How to write a script that gets from a user a paragraph of plaintext and a distance value

Tags: python

Write a script that gets from a user a paragraph of plaintext and a distance value. 
Then output this paragraph into an encrypted text using a Caesar cipher. Write this text to a file called `encryptfile.txt`. Then read this file and write it to a file named `copyfile.txt`.
This is what I have tried: 
 I can't seem to string all of these together into one code because I don't fully understand to to read, open, and write a file.

```
mapping = {} 
with open("copyfile.txt", "r") as keyFile: 
    for line in copyFile: 
        l1, l2 = line.split() 
        mapping[upper(l1)] = upper(l2) 
        decrypt = "" 
        with open("encrypted.txt", "r") as encryptedFile: 
            for line in encryptedFile: 
                for char in line: 
                    char = upper(char) 
                    if char in mapping: 
                        decrypt += mapping[char] 
                    else: 
                        decrypt += char print(decrypt)
```

Comment: Hi, Please add more information to the question like what's the issue with your code and to what part you want the help with. Follow the following guideline. [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hopefully what I edited helped you guys out.